Can you find what these letters might be?

ZXCSDE
XCVDFR
CVBFGT
BNMHJU


And if you want to do a similar pattern:


QWESDX
ERTFGV
TYUHJN
YUIJKM


They are:

 Pyramids of letters on a standard QWERTY keyboard

As shown here:

 




 Image credit: Denelson83, via Wikimedia Commons (CC BY-SA 3.0), with modifications

With the second pattern being:

 The same, but inverse pyramids.

However, what I can't figure out is:

 Why they jump: the first pattern is every key for the first several, but then skips V.  The second is every other key for the first several, but then Y is adjacent to T.


This is correct, the reason I jumped was to make it less obivous and didn't have much to do with the actual puzzle.
